# Incrementing number in page header causing micro stutter on page scroll

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I have a page header that dynamically displays the number of comments a user has scrolled through. See it in action here:

https://streamable.com/ae3lh

As you can see, as the counter is updated, the screen jitters a little bit...

To display the posts, I have the following html:

```
 <div>{{ currentCommentNumber }} of {{ commentCount ? commentCount : 0 }} Posts</div>
```

Where `commentCount` is set on page load and `currentCommentNumber` is updated using an `intersection observer`. Each comment has a specific id number, in this function I add all visible comments to an array and set the smallest number as the `currentCommentNumber`:

```
  onIntersection({ target, visible }: { target: Element; visible: boolean }): void {
    if(visible) {
      this.visibleElements.push(target.id.split("-")[1])
    } else {
      this.visibleElements = this.visibleElements.filter(el => el != target.id.split("-")[1])
    }
    this.currentCommentNumber = Math.min(...this.visibleElements) + 1;
  }
```

I confirmed this was an issue with the HTML updating, by removing the HTML but keeping the observer and the page scrolling went back to being very smooth. Is there a way to prevent this stuttering while "repainting" the header html? Thank you!

**note:**

I tried moving the counter element out of the header and into the content `div` just to confirm it wasn't a fixed position issue, and stuttering still persisted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This quote helped me fix my problem:

> Have you considered debouncing the HTML update so it doesn't happen
>   until the scrolling stops for a second?

For those interested, Ionic has an `(ionScrollEnd)` event on the `<ion-content>` tag (where all content is placed on a page) that is triggered when a scrolling animation stops, I simply called that method and updated the count there instead of attempting to update RIGHT when a new intersection event happens.

This fixed the jittering :)